# Tab visibility for the tab packaged in a managed package

Tags: managed-package, tab

I want to add a tab in my managed package and I want it to be available to system administrator only. I am selecting these settings while creating tab -

```
Apply a different tab visibility for each profile
```

`'Tab Hidden'` for all profiles, except system administrator for which it is `'Default On'`

In the next step, I have selected to include the tab only in my app and unselected other apps. I have also checked '`Append tab to users' existing personal customizations'`

Now when I add this tab to my managed package, it is still visible to all the non system administrator users as well. How can I make it available to only System administrator and add it to admin's tabs in my app(only) automatically.

Comment: When you made the changes to the profiles when including the tab, did you 'overwrite' the users' current settings with the checkbox?  If you don't, the change won't update the current profile settings.

Comment: Then it also won't add the tab to System admin's profile as well, which is a requirement.

Comment: Am looking for the answers to this issue. Can you post the answer?  All my tabs and pages are added to the profiles automatically  for Non-Admins

Answer (score 2):

Not 'an answer', but definitely this is kind of known issue. Please check this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ip4lAAA).

It definitely suggests "UNDER POINT THRESHOLD", so there needs to be more votes to ensure this is taken up by Salesforce.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: It's been some time I am out of StackExchange. Thanks Anup. I will move this to comment.

Comment: I need to have 50+ reputation in order to Comment!

Answer (score 0):

While installing the manage package in destination org, install it only for System Administrator.

Installing for All users, will automatically set the tab access to 'Default on' in the profiles which is why all the users get access to the tab.